# How to add Multiple Script files to Hyperledger Composer Playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a code distributed in 2 Script files. One is the **logic.js** provided by `Hyperledger Composer Playground`. And another script file - **optedServices.js** in which I have a function `getService()` defined. I need to call this function `getService()` in the code of logic.js. Please let me know how to do this. Thanks in advance - Madhu

I tried '`Add a file`' link in the bottom left corner. And drag and dropped the optedServices.js and pressed 'add' button. That included the file in UI of playground.

## The file logic.js contains:

```
function numToString(optedService) {

if (optedService == "") {
    return ""
}

var optedService2 = require('./optedService');

optedServices = optedService2.getService('2' + optedService);
 .......

return optedServices;
}
```

## The file optedService.js contains:

```
function getService (number) 
{

.
.
.

  return 'Sting1 & String2';

}


module.exports = {

        getService:getService

}
```

Expected result: 'Sting1 & String2'

Actual Result:

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network with transaction id 22b513d8dbbf765bd23e3f448c45d2464e19b6c35628e23989c0a25f6a018b49. Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: module is not defined
```